# Memory leak with apache, tomcat & mod_jk & mysql

Tags: linux, tomcat, memory-leaks, jvm, mod-jk

I'm running tomcat 7 with apache 2.2 & mod_jk 1.2.26 on a debian-lenny x64 server with 2GB of RAM.
I've a strange problem with my server: every several hour & sometimes (under load) every several minutes, my tomcat ajp-connector pauses with a memory leak error, but seems this error also effects some other parts of system (e.g some other running applications also stop working) & I have to reboot the server to solve the problem for a while.
I've checked catalina.out for several days, but it seem's there is not a unique error pattern just before pausing ajp with this message:

```
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Sometimes there is this message before pausing:

```
Exception in thread "ajp-bio-8009-Acceptor-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:597)...
```

& sometimes this one:

```
INFO: Reloading Context with name [] has started
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5482)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3847)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Can't create a new thread (errno 11); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug"...
```

& some other times the output messages related to some other parts of program.
I've checked my application source code & I don't guess it causes the problem, I've also checked memory usage using jConsole. The wanderfull point is that when server fails, is shows a lot of free memory on both heap & non-heap jvm memory space. As I told before, after crashing server, many other applications also fail & when I want to restart them it gives a resource temporary unavailable message (I've also checked my limits.conf file).
So I really really confused with this serious problem many days & i have really no more idea about it. So, can anybody please give me any kind of suggestion to solve this complicated & unknown problem ???
What could be the most possible reason for this error ?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem: it was not actually a memory leak, but the limitation in number of allowed threads for the VPS was caused the problem. My server was a Xen vps with default limitation of 256 threads, so when it reached the maximum allowed threads, the supervisor was killed some of running threads (that was cause of stopping some of my running processes). By increasing number of allowed threads to 512, the problem totally solved (of course if I increase maxThreads in tomcat settings, its obvious that the problem will rise again).

Answer (score 0):

What are your limits for number of processes?

Check them with uname -a and check maximum number of processes. If it's 1024, increase it.

Also, check the same thing for user which you are using to start it (for example, if you are using nobody user for your stuff, run su -c "ulimit -a"  -s /bin/sh nobody to see what actually this user sees as limits). That should show you a problem (had it couple of days ago, totally missed to check this).

In the moment when that starts happening, you can also count all your running threads and processes for that user (or even better to monitor it using rrdtool or something else) with "ps -eLf | wc -l" which will give you back simple count of all processes and threads running on your system. This information, together with limits for all particular users, should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use jvisualvm to check the heap usage of your jvm. If you see it slowly climbing over a period of time, that is a memory leak. Sometimes a memory leak is short term and eventually gets cleared up, only to start again.

If you see a sawtooth pattern, take a heap dump near the peak of the sawtooth, otherwise take a heapdump after the jvm has been running long enough to be at a high risk of and OOM error. Then copy that .hprof file to another machine and use the Eclipse MAT (Memory Analysis Tool) to open it up and identify likely culprits. You will still need to spend some time following refs in the data structure and also reading some Javadocs to figure out just what is using that Hashmap or List that is growing out of control. The sorting options are also useful to focus on the most likely problem areas.

There are no easy answers.

Note that there is also a command line tool included with the SUN jvm which can trigger a heapdump. And if you have a good profiler that can also be of use because memory leaks are usually in a piece of code that is executed frequently and therefore will show up as a hot spot in the profiler.